# Docker as non-root: How to write into mounted filesystem?

Tags: docker, rootless

I am running docker as non-root, after installing docker as advised here:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/
https://linuxhandbook.com/rootless-docker/

The docker version is

```
docker -v
Docker version 23.0.4, build f480fb1
```

and the host system is ubuntu 22.04

Now I wish to build an image, mount a volume from the host and write into it.

I built an example inspired from
https://dev.to/izackv/running-a-docker-container-with-a-custom-non-root-user-syncing-host-and-container-permissions-26mb
and
[In docker, writing file to mounted file-system as non-root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894086/in-docker-writing-file-to-mounted-file-system-as-non-root)
The docker file, named `trial_Dockerfile`, is a follows:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# Input arguments
ARG UID
ARG GID
ARG USER

# environment variables
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive"
ENV TZ Europe/Belgium

# Install some basic utilities and clean up
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    nano \
    ca-certificates \
    sudo \
    libx11-6 \
    openssh-server \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Create a sudo user
RUN apt install -y sudo && \
    addgroup --gid $GID $USER && \
    adduser --uid $UID --gid $GID --disabled-password --gecos "" $USER && \
    echo 'nonroot ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL' >> /etc/sudoers

RUN mkdir /home/$USER/app && \
    chmod -R 755 /home/$USER/app && \
    chown -R $USER /home/$USER/app

# Set the non-root user as the default user
USER $USER
WORKDIR /home/$USER/app
```

I built the image with

```
docker build --build-arg UID=$(id -u) --build-arg GID=$(id -g) -f trial_Dockerfile -t vplants/trial:1.0  .
```

and ran it with either

```
mkdir ~/Data && docker run -it --rm -v ~/Data:/home/jdurand/app:rw vplants/trial:1.0
```

or

```
mkdir ~/Data && docker run -it --rm -v ~/Data:/home/jdurand/app  -u `id -u $USER` vplants/trial:1.0
```

but in both cases, I obtained

```
jdurand@fca8fa4b16b9:~/app$ ls -la
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 root    root    4096 Nov 20 16:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 jdurand jdurand 4096 Nov 20 16:16 ..
jdurand@fca8fa4b16b9:~/app$ touch test
touch: cannot touch 'test': Permission denied
```

so the whole procedure did not have the expected result, user `jdurand` has no permission on `/home/jdurand/app` within the container.
Does anyone know how I could write into `~/Data` within the container please? (I mean without reinstalling docker and running it as the root user)

Comment: The "root" UID 0 will effectively map to the non-privileged user outside. So if you want to write data as "yourself" from within docker, you need to be root inside of the container. That is different to how "rootfull" docker works.

Comment: Thank you! Would it be possible to write data into a mounted volume as "sombody else but root" from within docker?

Comment: Yes, but you'll have to check what "real" uid the uid-in-the-container is mapped to, by checking subuid/subguid. For example, if uid X will be mapped to 231072 + X, if you followed the Docker guide exactly. So 231072 + X needs to have write permission on the "real" directory. (there might be an off-by-one error in there somewhere, so you need to double-check)